# Industrial practice for Rails 3 assets management

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Rails 3 is very flexible in terms of assets management. Stylesheets and javascripts are added and minified automatically in the asset directory. We can rename it to anything we want because the `application.js` will compile every `js` files before sending to the browser.

What I want to know is how is how do web developers usually manage their asset. For example, do they name their `js` files based on the model or controller? If I have a `Users` controller, do I separate the Javascript functions to a `users.js`, or lump everything in `global.js`?

I also know that we can store vendor's javascripts in the vendor directory, but it can be less manageable because we may ignore them accidentally, which I think it's better to put in the `assets` directory instead.

Anyway, [Rails Assets Management Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) is a good read, but I want to know what are the best practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the best practice is whatever is more comfortable to you and your fellow colleagues.

I usually keep everything on `application.js` itself… Then start breaking it down into additional files once it starts growing too much (like more than 30 lines). Some are horizontal concerns (like `tables.js`, `autocomplete.js` etc) and some are vertical ones (`products.js`, `customers.js` etc).

The best part of using an agile framework is the ability to refactor your code as you please, so you don't have to plan ahead how are you going to split your files.

Comment: +1 .. similar, though my apps thus far have been small enough to include all the horizontal stuff in application.js

Comment: Where do you keep your third-party files?

Comment: I just put them on `assets/javascript` and let it be compiled together with my own `application.js`. However, most of the third-party libraries I'm currently using are bundled as a gem (like `bootstrap` and `jquery`), so my assets directory is pretty clean.